# Find numbers that have no primes in their vicinity

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Let's assume I have a positive integer *N*. It is said to be **Lonely** if there are no prime numbers from *N-k* to *N+k*, where *k* is a positive integer smaller than *N*.

Given two integers *L* and *H*, how many **Lonely** integers are there between this range *[L,H]* (both inclusive).

I have assumed that *k<=L<=H<=100000*.
It is given that if *L=3480* and *H=3750*, the output is 2. (The 2 Lonely numbers are 3480 and 3750)

What I have done until now is first implemented a segmented sieve using the following code:

```
import math

def fillPrimes(chprime, high):
  ck = [True]*(high+1)
  l = int(math.sqrt(high))
  for i in range(2, l+1):
    if ck[i]:
      for j in range(i*i, l+1, i):
        ck[j] = False
        
  for k in range(2, l+1):
    if ck[k]:
      chprime.append(k)

def segmentedSieve(low, high):
  chprime = list()
  fillPrimes(chprime, high)
  prime = [True] * (high-low + 1)
  for i in chprime:
    lower = (low//i)
    if lower <= 1:
      lower = i+i
    elif (low % i) != 0:
      lower = (lower * i) + i
    else:
      lower = lower*i
    for j in range(lower, high+1, i):
      prime[j-low] = False
  
  for k in range(low, high + 1):
    if prime[k-low] and k>1:
      prime_list.append(k)

low = 3480
high = 3750
k = 10
prime_list = []
print("\nPrimes in Range %d to %d are"%(low,high))
segmentedSieve(low-k, high+k)
print(prime_list)
```

And then *tried* to implement a binary search on that list to find if there are any primes between N-k and N+k.

```
def left(prime_list, num): 
    start = 0; 
    end = len(prime_list)-1; 
    ans = -1; 
    while (start <= end): 
        mid = (start + end) // 2; 
        if (prime_list[mid] >= (num-k)): 
            end = mid - 1; 
        else: 
            ans = mid; 
            start = mid + 1; 
    print(ans)
    return ans;

def right(prime_list, num):
    start = 0;
    end = len(prime_list)-1;
    ans = -1;
    while (start <= end):
        mid = (start + end) // 2;
        if (prime_list[mid] <= (num+k)):
            start = mid + 1;
        else:
            ans = mid;
            end = mid - 1;
    print(ans)
    return ans;

num = 3481
k = 10
##if left(prime_list, num) != -1:
print(prime_list[left(prime_list, num)])
##if right(prime_list, num) != -1:
print(prime_list[right(prime_list, num)])
```

And this is where I hit a mental block.

My errors range from the fact that I am returning the primes shifted by one place in the array, which isn't a big deal, but I am getting errors that I cannot wrap my head around when I start to reach H. (when I receive negative numbers in *ans*, It starts to read the array from the end, as python likes to do.)

Any help/thoughts?

**EDIT:**
If we calculate the difference between two consecutive primes and they differ by more than 2k+1, we'll increment the number of Lonely numbers by the difference of the prime gap and 2k+1. This eliminates the need for the second part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply change the return statement to this, in both `left` and `right` methods ?

```
return max(ans, 0)
```

This will yield:

```
print(prime_list[left(prime_list, num)])
# > 3491
print(prime_list[right(prime_list, num)])
# > 3499
```

Comment: I've added an edit. I think that would be an easier solution to the problem.